# Soundcloud get track ID from link (PHP)

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

Okay, so I'm using php to post soundcloud widgets on my website(no need to explain why and how because thath's not wath's important)

Here is my code:

```
if (strpos($post['link'], 'soundcloud.com') !== FALSE)
{
    echo "<iframe width=\"500\" height=\"150\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" 
    src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/".$trackID."&amp;color=ff6600&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true\"></iframe>";
}
```

My variable **$post['link']** outputs the soundcloud link in this form https://soundcloud.com/alex-oancea/best-thing-about-you-original

What I would like to do is **get the track's id from the link** and declare it as **$trackID** because as you can see in my code(in the src="" part), the widget uses the track's ID

I have looked into the soundcloud API and many other threads on this site but I didin't find how to do this or how to write the code...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving

You can click the PHP button on the example and get a good way of getting a track ID:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');

// a permalink to a track
$track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/voca-nomen-tuum';

// resolve track URL into track resource
$track = json_decode($client->get('resolve', array('url' => $track_url)));
```

Now `$track->id` is your track ID.

Just be aware you need the SoundCloud API for this, and you'll probably have to register your app with SoundCloud to use the service. I have not had personal experience with any of this so I can't provide any information about those processes.

Comment: I tried everything but it gives me this error instead: 

Warning: Missing argument 2 for Services_Soundcloud::__construct(), called in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\acusticdream\feed-new.php on line 93 and defined in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\acusticdream\php\soundcloud-sdk\Services\Soundcloud.php on line 221

Comment: That means that you haven't instantiated your `Services_Soundcloud` class properly. Check [this link](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authentication) - click the PHP example again. It appears that the class expects 3 values when you instantiate it. `$client = new Services_Soundcloud('CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET', 'REDIRECT_URL');`

Answer (score 0):

If you experiment on your local machine (xampp in your case), you CANNOT make it work, beause the 'REDIRECT_URL' cannot be anything else but a valid link to a hosted domain. The API just does not accept (for the good reason) url's containing "localhost" or or "192.168.x.x"-style url's. This is simply because the API really sends info to the 'REDIRECT_URL' and it needs to be able to reach it.
You need to get in touch with your hosting provider and setup a "live" dev environement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the php-soundcloud from the mptre's Github:

Check https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving (and even the '/resolve' indicated in the 'see also' section).

You can get a good way of getting a track ID by this way:

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('YOUR_CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');

// a permalink to a track
$track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/voca-nomen-tuum';

// resolve track URL into track resource
$track = json_decode($client->get('resolve', array('url' => $track_url),        array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true))); 

// display all the information from that track resource
var_dump($track);
Now $track->id is your track ID.
?>
```

Just be aware you need the SoundCloud API for this, and you have to register your app with SoundCloud to use the service ([Register your app](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps)).

Another information is that Webservers where a basedir restriction is set and/or safe mode is active don't allow the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true option. [Here is a workaround for these webservers in the Soundcloud.php file.](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud/pull/30/files)